# CSS selector for two classes

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-selectors

I'm doing some work on SVG and I need to highlight specific elements of said SVG. I'm doing this by changing the element's class and making it a different color with CSS. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
  .series-a .bar {
    stroke: #00BCF0;
    .bar .highlight: {
      stroke: #FF5722;
    }
  }
  .series-a .bar {
    stroke: #00BCF0;
    .highlight: {
      stroke: #FF5722;
    }
  }
  .series-a .bar {
    stroke: #00BCF0;
    &&.highlight: {  
      stroke: #FF5722;
    }
  }
  .series-a .bar {
    stroke: #00BCF0;
  }
  .series-a .bar .highlight {
    stroke: #FF5722;
```

None of these has yet shown my highlight color or my style on chrome dev tools, so I wonder what am I supposed to be doing... We're also using post-css

Comment: For Multiple class remove space i.e `.bar.highlight `

Comment: Try providing a real [mcve]. Your CSS is useful (although what you have provided doesn't appear to be CSS and you've also trimmed the end off) but less useful then it would be with the markup you want to apply it to! It is often useful to provide your MCVE in the form of a [live demo embedded in the question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: give us compiled css, or like @Quentin said provide MCV exmaple

Comment: What is the `:` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it (duh)

```
  .series-a {
    .bar {
    stroke: #00BCF0;
    }
   .highlight {
        stroke: #FF5722;
      }
```

@Marvin yes, that wasn't it, luckily xD

Answer (score -1):

If an item has multiple classes, the right way is to stack them without a space.

`.a .b` means *select `.b` that is inside `.a`*

`.a.b` means *select `.a` that also has class `.b`*

```css
.item {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.item.highlighted {
  border-color: red;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<p class="item">This is the first item</p>
<p class="item highlighted">This is the second item</p>
<p class="item">This is the third item</p>
```